# filtering and showing which integers are already taken and which are available

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am having some difficulties implementing a method which can see what number(s) are already taken and what not.

I have a table called **Books**

```
//..

$table->integer('bookshelf_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
$table->foreign('bookshelf_id')->references('id')->on('bookshelves')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
$table->tinyInteger('bookshelf_number')->nullable();
```

And I have another table called **bookshelves**

```
//..     
$table->tinyInteger('number_of_slots');
```

so the steps are like this

The user selects a book
Select a shelf for the book to assign to
The shelf should filter which slots are already taken and which are available.
The user selects available slot and saves the book.
Here comes the problem.

I want to, when the user selects a bookshelf, the db filters which slots the selected bookshelf has available and which slots are occupied .

Would someone tell me what's the best way to implement this?

I was thinking to write a function which takes the id of the selected bookshelf and get the attribute 'number_of_slots' .. but now what? How I can make sure those slots are taken by some other book?

ps. I am using angularjs and laravel 5

**Update**

Based on what below answer was described I did the following on my example.

just to be clear: The DB tables below.

> - Book       -> **plates** 
>     bookshelf_slots -> **container_slots**
>     bookshelves    -> **plate_containers**

So here is what I did..

in my **plates** table I have the following

```
  $table->integer('container_slot_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
  $table->foreign('container_slot_id')->references('id')->on('container_slots')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

In **Plate** model I have

```
  public function containerSlot()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ContainerSlot');
    }
```

my **container_slots** table looks like this

```
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->integer('slot_number');
  $table->integer('plate_container_id')->unsigned();

  $table->foreign('plate_container_id')->references('id')->on('plate_containers')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

**container_slots** Model looks like this.

```
  public function plate()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Plate');
}

public function plateContainer()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PlateContainer');
}
```

my **plate_containers** table looks like this.

```
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->string('name', 25)->unique();
   $table->tinyInteger('number_of_slots');
```

And the model, **PlateContainer**

```
  public function containerSlot()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ContainerSlot');
    }
```

This actually worked.. well mostly. I get an empty array.

> Collection {#337 ▼   #items: [] }

Here is the way I call it in the route.

```
  $bookshelfWithAvailableSlots = PlateContainer::with(['containerSlot' => function ($q) {
    $q->join('plates', 'plates.container_slot_id', '<>', 'container_slots.id');
}])->find(3);

  dd( $bookshelfWithAvailableSlots->containerSlot);
```

**UPDATE #2 - with data**

At first I have implmented slightly differnt. But know this is what it returns.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Dr. Zechariah Effertz",
    "number_of_slots": 4,
    "description": "Nesciunt sint officiis est perspiciatis odio molestiae.",
    "material": "silicon",
    "plate_container_type_id": 5,
    "equipment_status_codes_id": 6,
    "storage_locations_id": 5,
    "created_at": "2015-10-25 18:22:33",
    "updated_at": "2015-10-25 18:22:33",
    "container_slot": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "slot_number": 8,
            "plate_container_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2015-10-25 18:22:34",
            "updated_at": "2015-10-25 18:46:25",
            "serial_number": 41,
            "supplier_id": 5,
            "equipment_status_code_id": 1,
            "plate_type_id": 5,
            "coating_id": 1,
            "geometry_id": 5,
            "document_id": 1,
            "metrology_data_file_id": 5,
            "project_id": 1,
            "plate_quality_id": 2,
            "crc-code": "5",
            "reason": "nice",
            "wafer_id": 3,
            "container_slot_id": 20,
            "data_representation_id": 1,
            "xray_measurement_id": 3,
            "deleted_at": null
        }, 

       {
            "id": 1,
            "slot_number": 5,
            "plate_container_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2015-10-25 18:22:34",
            "updated_at": "2015-10-25 18:46:25",
            "serial_number": 41,
            "supplier_id": 5,
            "equipment_status_code_id": 1,
            "plate_type_id": 5,
            "coating_id": 1,
            "geometry_id": 5,
            "document_id": 1,
            "metrology_data_file_id": 5,
            "project_id": 1,
            "plate_quality_id": 2,
            "crc-code": "5",
            "reason": "nice",
            "wafer_id": 3,
            "container_slot_id": 20,
            "data_representation_id": 1,
            "xray_measurement_id": 3,
            "deleted_at": null
        },
```

something like this

```
  $platecontainer = PlateContainer::with(['containerSlot' => function ($q) {
      $q->join('plates', 'plates.container_slot_id', '<>', 'container_slots.id');
    }])->find(1);

    return $platecontainer->number_of_slots;
```

will return `4`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add another table there for the slots. Something like the `bookshelf_slots` that will have a `slot_number` field that you would check if that slot has been taken or not.

```
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|       books       | bookshelf_slots |   bookshelves   |
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|        id         |        id       |        id       |
| bookshelf_slot_id | bookshelf_id    | number_of_slots |
| ...               | slot_number     | ...             |
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

This structure is described as `bookshelves` has many slots (`bookshelf_slots`) which can hold many `books` or `book` (optionally) belongs to a `bookshelf_slot` which belongs to a `bookshelf`.

**UPDATE**

Based on the steps you mentioned:

> The user selects a book Select a shelf for the book to assign to The shelf should filter which slots are already taken and which are available. The user selects available slot and saves the book.

When the user selects a `bookshelf` for the `book`, the `bookshelf` object can present a list of its `slots` with occupied/unoccupied status by querying the `bookshelf_slots` table with the following pseudo-conditions:  `bookshelf_slots.id` not in `books.bookshelf_slot_id` and `bookshelf_slots.bookshelf_id` is equal to the selected `bookshelf`'s `id.

In Laravel, assuming you have set up a `slots` relationship in your `Bookshelf` model, you can do something like the following:

```
$bookshelfWithAvailableSlots = Bookshelf::with(['slots' => function ($q) {
    $q->join('books', 'books.bookshelf_slot_id', '<>', 'bookshelf_slots.id');
}])->find($bookshelfId);
```

Then you can access the available slots by doing: `$bookshelfWithAvailableSlots->slots`.

Comment: Is there some sort of pseudo code where I can follow the steps and how to Implement this?

Comment: It worked almost. I updated my code in the question. Would you please guide me through it.. what's going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Could you add the data in your database for those tables?

Comment: I had some data already. But I guess something was wrong. Now I fixed it and I have the above updated code. I guess it works right?